# Requesting aliased :guifont rendering on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, font

Non-AA font rendering seems available everywhere except for *Windows*.

- In *MacVim*, this is possivle via `noantialias`.
- When using GTK2 front-end, the same can be achieved by adding `antialias=false` to the *fontconfig* query, e.g.: `Courier New:size=12:antialias=false:rgba=rgb`.
- For Motif, Athena and GTK1 front-ends, aliased rendering is the only option.

But how do I request it in the GUI version of *Vim* on Windows (`gui_win32`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 set gfn=Courier_New:h14:qNONANTIALIASED
```

Works for me in Win10

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's actually what I found myself after some searching, and that's exactly what crashes Vim 8.0 on Windows 7. But that's a different problem =)

Comment: No crash for me with Win7 though I installed Vim 8 some time ago (8.0.586).

Comment: I found these quality modifiers from the os_win.c vim code (which align to the window font quality options):

ANTIALIASED
NONANTIALIASED
CLEARTYPE
PROOF
DRAFT